# Saying that standard field PricebookEntryId doesn't exist?

Tags: apex

So at line "pbeIds.add(oli.PricebookEntryId);" eclipse won't save saying that "PricebookEntryId" doesn't exist, which is weird because it is the exact same code I copy and paste from dev sandbox.

Anyone got an idea?

```
public void updateRecord(List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList){

        Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>(); 
        for (OpportunityLineItem oli : oliList) 
            pbeIds.add(oli.PricebookEntryId);

        Map<Id, PricebookEntry> entries = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>([select Product2.Product_Type__c, Product2.ProductCode from PricebookEntry where id in :pbeIds]);

        for (OpportunityLineItem oli: oliList) {
            Product2 product = entries.get(oli.PricebookEntryId).Product2;
            oli.Product_Type__c = product.Product_Type__c;

            updateOliList.add(oli);
        }

}
```

Comment: Now maybe I'm old school, and this probably won't fix your problem.. Why don't you have brackets on your first loop?

Answer (score 1):

> **PricebookEntryId**
>
> **Properties:** Create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
>
> **Description:**
> Required. ID of the associated PricebookEntry. Exists only for those organizations
> that have Products enabled as a feature. You can specify values for either this field
> or ProductId, but not both. For this reason, both fields are declared nillable.

Might it be possible that your org is using a ProductID instead of a PricebookEntryId? I recommend you check your schema to verify whether that's not the case.

Comment: for example -- Opportunity Products are not available in Group Edition

Answer (score 0):

I would try to query the same field in developer console. It might be field level security permission issue. Make sure your administrator has access to the field.